# Use System.Reflection class to get method name and value to insert in database, is good practice?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ado.net

I'm working in something and I don't use `Entity Framework` for that now. I imagine a `method` for save data to the `database` avoiding the classic form use for the other people like:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionStringHere"))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;            // <== lacking
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT into tbl_staff (staffName, userID, idDepartment) VALUES (@staffName, @userID, @idDepart)";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffName", name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", userId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idDepart", idDepart);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(SqlException)
        {
            // error here
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

(Code take from other source)

The `method` that I imagine is get the name of the `getter method` in the `class` and then naming the `parameter` in the `query` with the same name for add the value. Example:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO [dbo.table] (user, pass) VALUES ('@User','@Pass')";

try
{
    // Create and Open Connection
    sQLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString);
    sQLiteConnection.Open();

    //  Begin Transaction
    sQLiteTransaction = sQLiteConnection.BeginTransaction();

    //  Create and Prepare Command
    sQLiteCommand = new SQLiteCommand(query, sQLiteConnection, sQLiteTransaction);
    sQLiteCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //  Add parameters to sQLiteCommand
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in UserClass.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        //  Jump ID Property
        if (property.Name == "IDUser")
            continue;

        //  Add values
        sQLiteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{property.Name}", property.GetValue(UserClass));
}
```

Can be that a good practice?

Psdt: Not is a professional project, I'm studying and practice.

Comment: Something is off in your code. Apparently you do not trust using, because you have using on the connection, the command containing the connection **and** a explicit close order in a seperate try...catch block. And for some reason you did not even put the connection and command into the same using block.

Comment: @Christopher I put only the essential part of the code. I have all in the complete method.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not that up to date with Entity, but I seem to remember it used attributes for that purpose.

So, **why is using attributes better than reflection here**?

#### It's loosely coupled.

Indeed, when you use the property's name as an identifier, you'll have to rework your database each time you modify its name. It may not ever happen, mind you, but it could... if not by you, by a future maintainer of your code. Whereas using an attribute, you can modify your property's name to your heart's content!

You could argue that if you modify your database, you have to modify your attributes... true, but the database is more critical than the program using it! So it has the priority in designing your applications.

#### It's not hacky

Attributes, to a decent C# dev, have a clear purpose of enriching code elements (classes, properties, methods...). You may not know what the attribute ultimately does, but you know that it's like a layer of added properties and/or behaviors.
Whereas when you see Reflection coded by someone else, you know you're in for a treat... of constant headaches. You don't know what the guy wanted to do right from the start. And that guy could be yourself in a year, when you look at your code again.

#### all hail Attributes!

I mean [look at that (Entity Framework Code First Data Annotations)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx), isn't it beautiful?

*Note: Reflection has its uses, obviously. But one should always at least try to avoid it, because 95% of the time, there's a better solution.*

Comment: I can't vote, but, I can say Thank you.

Comment: @CristopherJr.ViviecaRamos I'll take it :p

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is always make code less readable and it is a way too slow . Why are u not using ORM for that purpose? EF is not the only ORM there. You could use dapper

Comment: I put there, I'm only practice. I'm going to use a ORM in other moment. Good point.

Comment: i think it is cool to use already designed solutions, even when practice. Of course you could reinvent the wheel, but usually it is bad thing to do)

Comment: No, not at all. I don't want to reinvent the wheel haha. I'm going to check Dapper ORM. But, It's good think new things.